# RJB + Passenger. RJB appears not call Java

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, java-7, passenger, rjb

I'm having some issue with RJB and Passenger.

My system: 
Debian 6 Java JDK 7 Apache2 + Passenger Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.2.6

I'm using jasper-rails gem to read my .jasper reports over my RoR App.
On my developing machine (over webrick) everything runs Ok, but when i upload it to my Production server (Passenger + Apache2) when i click in the report link, it got lots of time processing and doesn't go to anywhere.

I made a test running "top" on linux at the same time i click to generate the report, and i realized that java process is not created, looks its not being called.

JAVA_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correctly set on system and over my environments.rb
Does someone have an idea about how to solve or debug this issue?

On log files i dont get any errors or warning.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance people.

Follows my environment.rb setup:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

ENV['JAVA_HOME'] = "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0"
ENV['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/client"

# Initialize the rails application
SIGMA::Application.initialize!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using the solution forked by Mahaswami Software: 
www.github.com/Mahaswami/jasper-rails

This guys modified the plugin to work properly with Passenger.

Thank You! ;)